# Get watcher icon in Jira

Tags: html, jira

I'm trying to get the watcher icon that we can see on Jira, to use it in one of my projects.

I could download the icon and just use it, but I'd rather use an URL like I'm already doing for the epics with  `https://ctl.atlassian.net/images/icons/issuetypes/epic.svg?format=png`

Any ideas? And also, where could I find all the other icons, in case they need them in the future?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/icons.html

Comment: https://atlassian.design/foundations/iconography